# Snowflake COPY command directory read

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image: image of the query in question]

```
COPY INTO SALES.SF_DEV.CUSTOMER_PARQUET_TGT FROM @EXTERNAL_STAGE_PARQUET_DEMO/partioned/customer/Country=INDIA/ MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_SENSITIVE FILE_FORMAT =  (TYPE = PARQUET);
```

The above command will load all the files recursively from dir Country=INDIA and all its sub-directories.

Que: Do we have an option to control recursive file loading, what I mean to load only files from Country=INDIA not from its sub-directories?

P.S. This image is with the pattern suggested by @gokhan

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use the pattern option?

```
COPY INTO SALES.SF_DEV.CUSTOMER_PARQUET_TGT 
FROM @EXTERNAL_STAGE_PARQUET_DEMO/partioned/customer/Country=INDIA/
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_SENSITIVE FILE_FORMAT =  (TYPE = PARQUET)
PATTERN = '[^\/]*';
```

The pattern is to prevent any sub-directories (files containing the slash characters).

My test environment:

```
ls @my_stage/test/Country=INDIA/; 

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                   name                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| s3://mysecretbucketname/test/test/Country=INDIA/data_0_0_0.csv.gz        |
| s3://mysecretbucketname/test/test/Country=INDIA/hododo/data_0_0_0.csv.gz |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+

ls @my_stage/test/Country=INDIA/ pattern = '[^\/]*';

+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                               name                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| s3://mysecretbucketname/test/test/Country=INDIA/data_0_0_0.csv.gz |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This didn't work, not loading files from the selected directory.

Comment: It worked for me. Are you sure the files are not loaded before? Can you share a file name with me?

Comment: Yes, it was not loaded even I truncated the table. filename is customer.parquet. Added screenshot from snowsql.

Comment: What do you see when you run: 

ls @EXTERNAL_STAGE_PARQUET_DEMO/partioned/customer/Country=INDIA/ pattern = '[^\/]*'

Comment: Output of the query: 0 Row(s) produced

Comment: I did several tests but it worked all the time. I don't understand why the pattern does not work on you. If someone else tests it, it would be great. There was a behaviour change on patterns, but as I remember it was about internal stages. Unfortunately I couldn't think any reason.

Comment: Could you share your dir structure? I'll try to replicate same in my env.

Comment: Rakesh updated my answer to show my environment